# Extracting a pack size from a column with mixed formats

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column `pack_size` in a table called `product_master_test`. The problem that I am facing is that the `pack_size` is in mixed formats, there is no uniformity to it.

For example:

- 4 x 2kg (pack size should be 4)
- 48-43GM (pack size should be 48)
- 12 x 1BTL (pack size should be 12)
- 1 x 24EA (pack size should be 24)

I've been thinking about different approaches, but I can't think of anything that would work without having a lot of IF statements in the query/PHP code. Is there a solution that I am missing?

I do have the file in `Excel`, if there is an easier way to process it using PHP.

I am not including any code, as I'm not entirely sure where to start with this problem.

Comment: If this is what you have, then I see no other way than to inventory all possible formats and write code to extract the actual pack size.

Comment: Is the pack size always the largest number?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, do you want to convert the string from column pack_size to an integer representing an actual pack size? If so, what about making an associative array with a string from table as a key and the acual pack size as value?

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately it might not be. Another example of a pack size that I have would be 12x500ML

Comment: @RenéBeneš Correct, I am trying to extract an integer from a string. Can you please expand more on your suggestion?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I've realised that some time ago! A solution that I thought about was if pack_size starts with 1, use 2nd part of the string as the pack size (1x24, 1-96's etc), if it is greater than 1, use 1st part of the string (4 x 2kg, 48-42GM, 12 x 1BTL, 12 x 500ML). There are bound to be exceptions though so I was wondering if there is another way

Comment: Can't you change you Excel format and add a column to separate the number of item and the size of each item ? Eg. 4 x 2kg => one column nb_item = 4 and size_item = 2kg ? Or to be more precise, 3 column like nb_item = 4, size_item = 2 and unit = kg ?

Comment: Is the pack size always one of the numbers present in a `pack_size` string? What I mean is: There's no format like this: "2 rows of 6 items", where the pack size should be 12?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger I could and that's what I've done so far, but it's a file with over 3000 lines and it's a manual process that takes close to an hour, which I want to eliminate

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, the pack size is always one of the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex to split the pack size could at least give you the various components which you can then (possibly) infer more from...

```
$packs = ["4 x 2kg","48-43GM","12 x 1BTL","1 x 24EA", "12 X 1 EA"];

foreach ( $packs as $size ) {
if ( preg_match("/(\d*)(?:\s+)?[xX-](?:\s+)?(\d+)(?:\s+)?(\w*)/", $size, $match) == 1 )  {
        print_r($match);
    }
    else {
        echo "cannot determine - ".$size.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

(regex can probably be optimised, not my area of expertise).  It basically splits it to be a number, some space with either a `x` or a `-` and then another number followed by the units (some text).  The above with the test cases gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4 x 2kg
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
    [3] => kg
)
Array
(
    [0] => 48-43GM
    [1] => 48
    [2] => 43
    [3] => GM
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12 x 1BTL
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 1
    [3] => BTL
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1 x 24EA
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 24
    [3] => EA
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12 X 1 EA
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 1
    [3] => EA
)
```

With the `else` part it should also give you the ones it cannot determine and perhaps allow you to change it accordingly.

Comment: This might actually work, I will try to implement the suggested solution and let you know the outcome, thank you so much!

Comment: I have tried it with the current data, and there are some examples that cannot be determined. Probably a regex tweak will do the job, but same as you, I'm not a regex master! Seems like the issue is with pack_size in format of "12 X 1 EA" "2000 X 1 EA", "6 X 1 EA". Looks like the code dealt with about 90% of the lines which is already brilliant!

Comment: You're a star. That has done it! I have only 3 products now that cannot be determined which are all to do with weighed items (pack size: 2.5k, pack size: 0.80k and pack size: 10KG). I'm not worried about them though because I can handle them in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could present an associative array of all the strings from the table as keys corresponding with correct `pack_size` you desire.

```
$packsize = ["4 x 2kg" => 4, "48-43GM" => 48, "12 x 1BTL" => 12, "1 x 24EA" => 24]; //add all pack_sizes here
echo $packsize["4 x 2kg"]; // Output: 4
```

Now you could get the acutal pack size via the key of associative array. It could save some time you would spend making if/else conditions or switching the input. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with this approach, so correct me if so.

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for a scalable solution

Comment: Yeah, the file has over 3100 lines and the pack sizes very pretty much for every product, so going about it that way won't work

Comment: I'm not sure how possible that would be if the column doesn't hold any standard in labeling the pack sizes. The program can't guess which of the numbers is the actual pack size if it appears on different spot everytime. It will always need some user supervision. Couldn't the characters in the end of the string provide little insight on which number is the correct pack size?